# Getting error 'for' loop limit must be a number

Tags: lua

when implementing for loop I get error 'for' limit must be a number and here is my code,and my input is number phone,can someone help me edit, let me complete. Thank you

```
local a = tonumber(nameInput.value); 
for  i = 1,tonumber(nameInput.value),1 do       

        line = fh:read()
        if line == nil then break end
        
        a = a +tonumber(nameInput.value);
```

Comment: It seems your `nameInput.value` does not contain a number.  For example, it might be an empty string or `nil`

Answer (score 1):

`tonumber` will return `nil` if the value passed to it can not be converted, a phone number like `123-456-7890` is not a valid input to
`tonumber` it does not know what to do with the `-`s in the string.

Some documentation on `tonumber`:
[Lua 5.3 Manual: tonumber](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tonumber)

to handle this you can use `or 0` in lua to create a ternary of sorts.

```lua
local a = tonumber(nameInput.value) or 0; 
for  i = 1,tonumber(nameInput.value) or 0,1 do       

  line = fh:read()
  if line == nil then break end

  a = a +tonumber(nameInput.value);
end
```

now when `tonumber(nameInput.value)` returns nil you will use the default value of `0`. With this change you will no longer see the error but when `nameInput.value` is a non-numeric value you will also no enter your loop.